# Creating a Python package with kfp component - How to ensure compatibility with multiple kfp versions?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines, kfp

New here...

I am creating a Python package that contains a Kubeflow Pipelines - kfp component (@dsl.component), my plan is to install this package (requires kfp v2.0) and import the kfp component in multiple pipelines...
the things is people who will install the Python package and import the kfp component, might use a differente kfp version such kfp v1.8, so what would be the best way or is there a way to make the kfp component from the package compatible will both kfp versions (kfp v1.8 and kfpv2.0)?